# Print a Quinella Table

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number

> **ALERT: IN CASE YOU DOUBT, NO PUN ON "QUINE" IS INTENDED**

In regulated horse-racing for gambling, bets called *Quinella bets* [exist and in which a person bet on the first two places of a race.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quinella) In racecourses, usually there is a display which shows the odds of a specific combination as below:

[image]

(This picture is a cropped picture from Hong Kong Jockey Club. QIN stands for Quinella)

### Challenge

Write a program or function, receiving either lines of strings or an array, print or return an ASCII Quinella table with the following format:

```
 QUINELLA  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  |     
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
     | 8\1 | 162 | 7.2 | 11  | 109 | 4.5 | 6.0 | 11  | 999 | 11  |     |     |     |     |  1  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
  9  | 37  | 9\2 | 11  | 999 | 41  | 350 | 75  | 24  | 999 | 31  |     |     |     |     |  2  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 10  | 8.2 | 84  |10\3 | 75  | 999 | 85  | 48  | 8.1 | 138 | 191 |     |     |     |     |  3  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 11  |     |     |     |11\4 | 45  | 6.4 | 999 | 287 | 473 | 60  |     |     |     |     |  4  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 12  |     |     |     |     |12\5 | 15  | 8.9 | 40  | 175 | 378 |     |     |     |     |  5  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 13  |     |     |     |     |     |13\6 | 26  | 999 | 15  | 860 |     |     |     |     |  6  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 14  |     |     |     |     |     |     |14\7 | 727 | 100 | 37  |     |     |     |     |  7  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
     |  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  |     |  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  |
```

In this challenge, the numbers in the middle are calculated from the input by a specific algorithm, which will be explained later.

## Specification

**Input**: Your program or function must receive one of the two formats as below:

- **Lines of Strings**: The first line will be `<number of horses> <number of bets>`, following by `<number of bets>` lines of `<horse 1> <horse 2> <amount of bet>`.

Example:

```
10 100
1 2 100
3 4 500
5 6 100
7 8 2000
9 10 10
(... 95 more lines)
```

- **Array**: An array or tuple, with 3 elements, `[<number of horses>, <number of bets>, <bets>]`, where `<bets>` is a 2d array consisting of `<number of bets>` elements, each element consists of 3 elements, `[<horse 1>, <horse 2>, <amount of bet>]`. *As a special rule for functions, passing the tuple as 3 arguments is allowed.*

Example:

```
[10, 100, [
 [1, 2, 100],
 [3, 4, 500],
 [5, 6, 100],
 [7, 8, 2000],
 [9, 10, 10],
 ... 95 more elements
]]
```

- You may assume all inputs are valid.
- You may assume `1 <= <horse 1> < <horse 2> <= <number of horses>` in both cases.
- You may assume `9 <= <number of horses> <= 14` in both cases.

**Processing**: The odds for each quinella pair `<horse 1>, <horse 2>` (unordered, i.e. `1,2` and `2,1` are considered identical) is calculated as follows:

```
Odds = <Total bet amount of all pairs> / <Total bet amount of the pair> / 2
Maximum Odds: 999, Minimum Odds: 1.1
```

In case you doubt, **the odds will be 999** if `<Total bet amount of the pair> == 0`.

The result should be rounded to the nearest 0.1 if `Odds < 9.95` (in this case, the `.0` must be retained if necessary), and to the nearest integer if `Odds >= 9.95`.

**Output**: Replace each ***bold-and-italic number pair*** with the corresponding odds calculated in the previous step. Leave the cell blank if any of the number in the pair is larger than `<number of horses>`.

```
 QUINELLA  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  |     
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
     | 8\1 | 1,2 | 1,3 | 1,4 | 1,5 | 1,6 | 1,7 | 1,8 | 1,9 |1,10 |1,11 |1,12 |1,13 |1,14 |  1  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
  9  | 8,9 | 9\2 | 2,3 | 2,4 | 2,5 | 2,6 | 2,7 | 2,8 | 2,9 |2,10 |2,11 |2,12 |2,13 |2,14 |  2  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 10  |8,10 |9,10 |10\3 | 3,4 | 3,5 | 3,6 | 3,7 | 3,8 | 3,9 |3,10 |3,11 |3,12 |3,13 |3,14 |  3  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 11  |8,11 |9,11 |10,11|11\4 | 4,5 | 4,6 | 4,7 | 4,8 | 4,9 |4,10 |4,11 |4,12 |4,13 |4,14 |  4  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 12  |8,12 |9,12 |10,12|11,12|12\5 | 5,6 | 5,7 | 5,8 | 5,9 |5,10 |5,11 |5,12 |5,13 |5,14 |  5  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 13  |8,13 |9,13 |10,13|11,13|12,13|13\6 | 6,7 | 6,8 | 6,9 |6,10 |6,11 |6,12 |6,13 |6,14 |  6  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
 14  |8,14 |9,14 |10,14|11,14|12,14|13,14|14\7 | 7,8 | 7,9 |7,10 |7,11 |7,12 |7,13 |7,14 |  7  
-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----
     |  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  |     |  8  |  9  | 10  | 11  | 12  | 13  | 14  |
```

- Each cell is 5 characters wide.
- You must center the odds, and if you cannot balance the margins, make left margin 1 character less wider than right margin.

### Test Cases

[Here is a TIO driver which generates random test cases. No hard-coded test cases will be provided.](https://tio.run/##rZRvb6NGEMbf8ylGvIKYEHb5Z87xVW11p6a6Jjq198pY8l6MEyIHOCBXrOB@9fSZxUns3KXqi7M0axie/c3s7OzeqK@quazzqj0uymX28FXV1G6qjKZkNm2dF1cmnZzQr9dl2WTPrrImU9W12pikGsqL6q6lVVnfqlYTirvbz1l9sfqtrJusAesP1V67tSqW5a1l0xFFNKKEem9isLzOLst6@T1d4gkohec9aRVUs/nEQDSL3zu8exP8nT5i8DIa2XRvEH@vvkN9kR4CAO/Ql/8rnRj093W@zsgCfUpfbJpVmD7n1H50LCyVlFvdNdfWzHXdIZDblHVrWblDNzZN31JOx3hySNLREVkvucJjlk09eXN7YmwN47IsmnKduevyyjLPePfekIlP@YqsYfeft19Xcn/CYZrOY9kxnVuAdrtSrkjZBh3M7NybMi8WtNBZZGt01EHEoaNsOoz3@58X5@6QTL7aWLNX4juk5g5quF6jDjYi6HZpy1atf8lalPt@69AVl@Uv9nHbOFQuddvdb3VDHeTOy36cPZt1Mw/0bibmc95m65UvPWpso9rdTPLG7YUbTXfO7X6kKYmhdw8X9dzCT9oNtB3v4wSPp9NvJmx2E3TTY1mQ70U/QWuc7GXNJNMxMW52SSNbvRk89S0lSWLvKHjkb0@7xd5TEq54FOCRBVxKVMMBkSuEV7ct3@ddttxNSdwk5DBb7kDOcpk31Vrxwhb08ewcaZCE@bAAFsIiWAwbw5IenQwTMOgEdCLojZ7GaSp64UiYDwtgISyCxbAxLIFhMgZWCpYK1goOJAyGjyGiJE1lL4GRwEhgJDASGAmMhEIyRjJGMkYyRg4YaXB@YxYkOpiXpn7vA@QD5APkA@QD5APks8RnkM8gn0H@APINXuSYvyU6YU@PIk2DPgAqACoAKgAqACpgVMCagFEBo4IBFRhcqzG7E71sT49DCWSahn0IWAhYCFgIWMiwkGEhi0KGhQMsNLjoY/YkunyeHodS6koIP02jPgIuAi4CLmJcxLiIcRGrogEXGbx/Y35JeGBcoHGBxmHUBRFBmsZ9DGAMYMzAmIExA2MGxgMwNl7tlP9socXkxY2YFhd37dOluP9p17IuxrxdGAv3VlVWx1dwt/P1g2/DPuufjZsXy6y7WFk4bTb9RCbxobP0YRmOngn/G9rYbqWW74qlFdr2cE32i@HBQhw@rsf8G5lunVWZai0R8kWz0F4DUrjX6jKzTBwlXPWE803mx09n5@8@fPjZxIX48PAv)

### Winning Criteria

Shortest code in each language wins as per the rules of code-golf challenges. No standard loopholes allowed.

Comment: I take it that `9 <= number of horses <= 14` based on the test generator, and the output format? Additionally, is input in the form of a tuple `(number of horses, number of bets, [array of bets])` acceptable?

Comment: @Οurous I think yes. I'll modify to clarify this.

Comment: Can the three-element sub-arrays be taken as tuples? And may the bet values be taken as floats-with-integer-value instead of integers? Eg: `[[Int]]` becomes `[(Int,Int,Real)]`

Comment: @Ourous of course yes (for both questions) (I'd say array and tuple are to be treated the same here but when I was building this challenge I was coding with JavaScript so...)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES8), 321 bytes

Takes input as `(number_of_horses)(bets)`. The number of bets [is not taken](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12442/58563).

```javascript
n=>b=>' QUINELLA  '+(y=e='',g=(x,y)=>b.map(([X,Y,b])=>k+=X-x|Y-y?0:b,k=-(x>n|y>n))|k,F=x=>y>16?e:`|+
`[x?y&1:2]+(Y=y/2,s=y&1?'-----':(x%15|Y%8?x?Y>7?x>7?x:x<7?x+7:e:x-Y?y?x<15?~g(x>Y?Y:x+7,x>Y?x:Y+7)?(k=.5/k*g())<999?k.toFixed(k<9.95):999:e:Y:x:x+7+'\\'+x:y-2?Y+7:e:e)+e).padStart(s[2]?4:3).padEnd(5)+F(++x<16?x:!++y))(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVdda1tHEH33r3AfUt3be@XszM5@CcuXPiRQCIVSChG2IU6smFSpHGJTrsDkr7uzuzMbNQZbq/2amTNnzqz/vvn35uHD109fHpf7@9vt88f183598X59sTj946/ffn/15s2vp6eLoTust@vFYrxbd/N46HnH2T83X7ru8u24Gd9f88RuWL9dzk@b5WEyq/fjbr3s5ov90@Fi3/dPu/H1el5fHC7AT9vVu6fh5N3lPB1@hhVeD91mfXiJ48Oav0@LZf5ZrLr5BbinzYs4zdPmIkxz/l3N5/x3CKvtal5upsM0n4Obvt2xpc20WfHKmEfzajOEfup26zP3cvfLXdf35ymlaXf2eP/607y97Xbn6Sy5fsWzfBefzGeHxdXVYphXhyVOm2Jk2w/b/uzLze2fjzdfH7uHS7yeaGXL1Kv9bef64XU3DOyFZ6M/DcOh7zvsnz/c7x/uP2/PPt/fdR@71J90l5du9KOF6/ESxzAmWwZuRJkAm0d@jKMj4pHl3YE/45hGMClPAS96i3LQ8yfxQVuOpfId8kXey3GkstWPFGVvqofiGEGMUTA8cmIMRhzRlFN2dNYf@eh4M5gooxicXBma/yEUuzzlyy7228ndVi/wVt3UO63RgXgNyddhtieDIJ@WoOzmSMQWOQ0y5c28MDqxQCnKJsByzgpKmHF0VhZR8APxlkeCCa8pAlHgB4Qy4k3e1MVUboAcpamLVGIpuVBQoYJKnNwosaCTqVSQ5OMOxcmSuAyud@IuSk5sY4QEWx0K2bVUbNlR0SON3iZQDwVrrGtudMmrO8IMxsrLjcGQBgtyl1WzxVpObWUUz1iByDnlmPgTjJEorDfiSCFZQT1YcaVuZ5dsC4BA7iR3jGM2C5ScuFk953RFRcKqFSJlp9OasAoLUpLbE4qnoLXlTNBAnZH0uKM6yeYQk8RQUloqFzSXFIQbEDyJN9GDUDVozUJD3UXxlDTTVgYehQyIWr1WQafgWoDeCHvIoOAdU2wJbGeVwCSuesEfG4G4lFUegldOggpVUE4CgY5MOKrq7DTKmsvsUyjgOOqafIoCCVASk1ZTnEAljrN@3Z8Op4ur/dV@0Z@c/F9egYq@suNUomKjLGNWalEqtioV3wUjKuWjZAYUOqzJBobfpFJqfBNALVkwXGOx6JfJ81ErOVZ55amAUp/kax7ZGoCO0FV6sJsea0XxmSQ16Uz1i8ZmjqzuR3VG2wYF5UBINS6@NNb6ZveL0ZQnK/p8GVplrlRO1rAWTEsvVUvMA3CtPlS0q83sWfLaJfISZEssoEG4lCq0mKetRAWt@dT0Z5cUA0@mMTppAQSJhpMqCeIjTpTZaVjRoAgHENag2ZuixPm@aDTbUC4RV72AnoK2HauAoViAGGqzEcZk@SHXmACl3WWeolYQFwSJBKWoAkdJSCySwGctaO@J6BrFQQu@OsD7KuqFODLk4ympENX0sMfO6YniSkFA8sMnNNlO5S4UcmSWlgBzMOxBaVW@NABMWileqUU6wFbq1HQgRWr3oNOdAEWmvNCmSK45kokcdaxkM1WCU0mw02LC5KSEqzjEip3WbCVlpViClgIxia42nbwqqeX14JRSqNgm3Ra11tJxWcQKW42tEbKYycscVamcqiuiMFYZDhX0MgraMPW9AvZ7tVLRQeEmtukAre8nTXEgrR4r3S2XozSeHE9LQJAr@bycIWmNUKPxDYyGeXUqp8g23lolP2lf4bdqTW120kZQVYCGOUSsWsA7fDPphZS5gkKUOvNWnl1ehMLb@rjJwbYUewPCYzKtPnxQuY5We9EP75HMo@NGWgrAh5ZIlG4oqUN9NGcBPG5q5WUKTlMdWomAMUl0lZR8schfOlJ/1hdsr2hSlFRgsVGM6lsEmoZDbTv6TNBGBWSbhRA0404LTvUS5ZWj79xQnu51rSpzZbxvefOktcygtnTJ@yu/XKSxZGlJP3Qn830AoO@0ql22Jr0uk/zTUC7xTSj1SApRgHeM2XXfP/8H)

### How?

#### Main part

```javascript
n => b =>                       // n = number of horses; b[] = bet array
  ' QUINELLA  ' + (             // append header
    y = e = '',                 // e is the empty string; start with y = '', coerced to 0
    F = x =>                    // F = main recursive function, taking x
      y > 16 ?                  //   if y is greater than 16:
        e                       //     return an empty string and stop recursion
      :                         //   else:
        `|+\n`[x ? y & 1 : 2]   //     append a linefeed if we are at the beginning of a row
        + (                     //     or either '|' or '+' depending on the parity of y
          Y = y / 2,            //     define Y = y / 2
          s =                   //     define s:
            y & 1 ?             //       if y is odd:
              '-----'           //         s = 5 hyphens
            :                   //       else:
              [cell content]    //         s is set to the content of the cell
        )                       //
        .padStart(s[2] ? 4 : 3) //   prepend leading spaces
        .padEnd(5) +            //   append trailing spaces
        F(++x < 16 ? x : !++y)  //   append the result of a recursive call
  )(2)                          // initial call to F() with x = 2
```

#### Cell content

The cell content is computed with [a huge cascade of ternary operators](https://tio.run/##hVRti9tGEP7uX7H90HhVrR3t@6442fRDDgohUEohxmeIL6cciVP7yB1FAtO/fpldzai6XNIazM7O6zPPzOrT/u/9/fsvH@8eFsfTTfv4oTk2q@tmNWe///nbm1evX//K2LzkfdM287m4bXgn@gI8ln/t7zjfvhUbcb0DxaFs3i6682bRr6v6WhyaBe9Wx3O/OhbF@SAum65Z9Svp1m397lxeHd9tu3X/QtZqV/JN079U4r6B@3q@SL95/chnjHXsZyYtO7MNCIGtQZWUw8lAu2J@vCXL0ztoRrmeatnFN35JVzI/0dRPrO3sW23HFlB/mqN/lvEigX@qZOyfW55wQiz866GuYKTqQLVJquJZIGP8wBq2tOwlO7Bf2C0vCigRY/yOK2OH5cPp8mPX3kAUeC2jLZ551d@Jg3yz//NqZ/9l3/yQxh@NA/qF//zqag7H4EQOPfCsJg1uJnP6N0kCNNzaWQEe7WOxvNvf/PGw//LA77dqtza1zqpXxxtui/KSl2V3AevY1T@VZV8UXBWz2fvT8f70uV1@Pt3yDzwWM77dWuGEljuxVcKLqLNghUKF1ElyIghrDEgavD2cQUQhq5hUEoxOKwx0cBoI1Dks5rtMiZzDcGWyqxMmoG8cgoIIEosZX4FksZgUSqgqR2lhtZtgtOAsq4BS8BZT@hG/97kuqFz2AtwWc2tK4DTBpJy6IgFRy@gGMdVDweOpjcze0AnWMpaajMkZDMJiBRMDOkmV4zSypBKPVqNRIX8S0YKEnICNGAhIv1QyS@DkqsEYcwaZuqwGo8m95FkQqXIg1cBwA/aiLKpiZhLCrUKQeXCJXGcRrsKZ6HEjsNkBkE/QYq6lBbFnqHsdJSFErtVgs8JGR3BwM4Arhxl9ZahZibk0lc3V0miHjQKNRoqspR1DPL6qsAvtKgSSlyyz7jVCGdwBkh4bMBJzGjvlMZWVJlqEOSCHcQViQlMVY2g7Lb0JTbQoEzF7VIhU0tuyladGbYXjsZN3ksopFbGHPNL8ciXN0njcDemdQTTBSVxVT29WjqzbgEgNTVqj4BQug1L0ejWRbrwdG3QVbo@pFPIdYhgHOMbSAhuE6pB/NS4QPGX6PHhHOynpQ@VpJ6WRJFV@8qoTaIU2m7aPqJDTrofhm4CUSBOxpKYRR0mfOJj6rigevwI), which is neither easy nor very interesting to detail here.

One key part in there is the formatting of a bet:

```javascript
~g(                             // invoke g():
  x > Y ? Y : x + 7,            //   first horse
  x > Y ? x : Y + 7             //   second horse
) ?                             // if g() didn't return -1:
  (k = .5 / k * g())            //   compute amount_of_all_pairs / amount_of_this_pair / 2
  < 999 ?                       //   if the result is less than 999:
    k.toFixed(k < 9.95)         //     output it with the proper number of decimal places
  :                             //   else:
    999                         //     force result to 999
:                               // else:
  e                             //   output an empty cell
```

#### Bet amount processing

The helper function \$g\$ computes the total bet amount for a given pair of horses, or the total bet amount of all pairs when invoked with no argument. If at least one of the horses is not valid, it returns \$-1\$ instead.

```javascript
g = (x, y) =>                   // x = 1st horse, y = 2nd horse
  b.map(([X, Y, b]) =>          // for each bet of amount b on horses (X, Y):
    k +=                        //   update k:
      X - x | Y - y ?           //     if (x, y) is not matching (X, Y):
        0                       //       add 0 to k
      :                         //     else:
        b,                      //       add b to k
    k = -(x > n | y > n)        //   start with k = 0 if both x and y are valid horses
                                //   otherwise, start with k = -1
  ) | k                         // end of map(); return k
```

Comment: [Holy ternary Batman! o.Ô](https://tinyurl.com/y87uaupt)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I actually gave up detailing all these ternary operators. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>500</s> <s>448</s> 444 bytes

```python
R=range(1,15)
h,_,b=input()
Q=eval(`[['']*16]*9`)
Q[8][1:6]=R[7:13];Q[8][8:16]=R[7:]
for i in R:
 if i<8:Q[i][i]=`7+i`+'\\'+`i`;Q[i][::15]=[['',7+i][i>1],i]
 for j in R:v=sum(v*((A,B)==(i,j))for A,B,v in b);x=min(999,0**v*999or.5*sum(zip(*b)[2])/v);X,Y=i<j<=h and[i,j-7,j,i-7][i>7::2]or(0,0);Q[X][Y]=x<10and round(x,1)or int(x+.5)
Q[0]=[' QUINELLA  ']+R[1:]+['']
for l in Q:print('-----+'*15+'-----\n')*(l<[' '])+'|'.join(map('{:^5}'.format,l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVbbbuM2EH3PV@hNkq2kHN6pRAW2QB8KLAokQIFdKGrtYHcbBYkduImR3r495fAijmv4gRQ5tzNnjvT858v9fsff32@Gw3b3@9cGOlDt2X33W3c3zLvn15emPbsevh63j81mHOt6WoGeVm7jn452GqHX03Azmh7EdBme2B7So@ns2/5QzdW8q276s2r@Vs1Xtr8e58n/h41Zz5t1fXtbrzfz5jI87ntQ04BhOn/qr30PUzdPZxU6eoiOjsMfr0/NcdU0H7of2mFo5u6hbfGC33dHvHTXXr4NT/Oucc51bLU6rvxif7hQKzT9a35uVnftyKf2u2N7@an7PMxXD1fDfbXdfRm9t3PTPXTzucH4pu/5tD80rGOtz/HTNH6ehrcrYP5uddi/7r40bx20WOfupXlbXygEhvki6ur6l59@/vHjxw9VVU/rGw/VtEYAAyqPmOd1/3xAs/ocf@t6BWod17e7ul01j1feSz216/qf@uJh7wt62j439d/9r@rf@sK7edq@dI9t@/4@gugqDryrxtF0Fe6Ai8lvlV8x3AHuoKv8keC4lvjUWylI91xXSVz6G/5Mu2DA4i1lsjN07bhM3hQ6MGljvY8SRUK4pKONTWufnS5LMFaUkJzEEJylA@9VhAgulmJ5sQBGKjFpbVIaJtiCFmkTalHMJnPvbjnhKSuIKIQ1jxaCYmVThjZB5e8DVhshQC/@kuEkW8nTCVpJV4IAl6YAz63N/ryRlpBd@CdGkbDckeqV0yWughDKRiNrMjQqARvKD8SQpDxtNClQO5d7tuSOz9FOGsj@xVKyi3YxtE4blTsRzFxuJKal0j1sqqIEO2mStSqliGYxDRNwUuSaVgQKToKY2KfUAdCa9ACESEDLREoZe26hgKwUBUzlsnmhqC9B5vABquQU@5@jGVxndL29yczDAwoKN7TbJ1CCZKV4kTmCDiQv/Y25xwKdEwU7vkw6MivPI/JN24wknmgGFDHgqlwF/yuhjC2khcixxAHryDSB1LokCyLPB951hOmcVG4JnjHxOClOEBCzQunMakgBjSIDaWgqVknK4wVfyIimkdF6ccFToEXwGCtxo@hECIzIG/QgZVFCAA25oNBn4k9Hq5A7JRjuDWGbTajhtBRJEFmIkrlbNCYOkyVN4Yyou6Bog9I5PSRO8YjMlTQjHokT58TIIp8ec0pjJ6Dc4yTBCFhiJOGZLhMn8jpoAdDMyhuFA5E7MERLVR6AKHCcqAcnjj3PSZXKFlIushoqZqQ/kcy2iAbY7CTEW8SU5yZn3RCLikWqwf/fKkDLTZ0VZCwVoYzlvLzTzMIYHBWmTkokDeemDK5QnIxO1gh860pSuswWOmtaxoBRUAU9EszSI6ZKY4QjCFiClIkSuwjO8gLNnwGxUEGGSylZqvEybohr4GRjoHy6QPJBVTfhpohOZ/b5pXJQGE7bDvpESwVRqzK0LH17JIF0lmJLpoNryjeR5w3VjpFXnBQn0rUoT9ioMgwkf6BD7jR5E@eM8YMAVEFFK0bKdEVrOf3G0US1LaeKwItKgSuYOvK1wE@ozASZb/DCNk3/AQ)

Comment: I cannot test right now, but would `x+.5` work over `round(x)`?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yeah, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>498</s> ... 483 bbytes

[Doesn't take](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/12442#12442) the number of bets.

```
import StdEnv,Text
q=""
j=join
$h a=replaceSubString" 0""  "(" QUINELLA"+(j("\n"+j"+"(repeatn 16"-----")+"\n")[j"|"[q<+cjustify 5[c\\c<-: ?h a u v]\\v<-[0..15]]\\u<-[0..8]])%(9,9^9))
?h a u v|u<1=q<+v rem 15|v>14=q<+u rem 8|u>7|v>7=q<+v=q<+(v+7)*sign(v rem 7)
|u==v=u+7<+"\\"<+v|v<1|u>1=q<+u+7=q
#p=sort[k+if(u>=v)7 0\\k<-[u,v]]
#r=sum[z\\(x,y,z)<-a|[x,y]==p]
|r>0.0#r=sum(map thd3 a)/r/2E0
|r<9.95=snd(sort[(abs(e-r),e<+".0")\\e<-[1.1,1.2..1E1]]!!0)%(0,2)=q<+toInt r
|p!!1<h="999"=q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVrbbhzHEX0Ov2K1dgBuOKK7@t4G10GA6MGAESRR8kQywJqiLMoiJfEWy@C3R@numalzOMsHYnZ3pru6rqdOzcWHy93N1@uPbx4@XK6ud1c3X6@uP328vV@9vn/z6uZx@Nflb/cHn7fr9cH77fuPVzcH375b7ba3l58@7C4uXz/8/Pr@9urml/XKrNer1fpwvfrHv3/826uffvrL@ujw/eH67GZ99H59tD6sT1zu7m9WEtcv2996c9R@3Jy@Xz@tTz@fHF28f7i7v3r7ZRVOL87OLk5efr/6c91q9bB6PD87ezx5eWqOjyWc1w8P44d8fr7542EZyn/KZnMw3/z0cCLbut7j6vbyeiXh6fEH8e2Lh/5Ffnr4IdXvUr@n/Tt8PEqbP91d/XJzOD6TNgdPD9vt4/bhKJ1UKc/W9c6nxxOpj/al6/fbzwfffNreVUWd/np09fbw4Yft4yatzNnZr1W4h@Hx/Pzgm9vt3cP16e9nZ4e/DV@G3zcnL3dPp/XyfLv9dH7wdPuDOTbjTYfXu0@r@3dv3Gq3@e72O/vK1J9PynEJ27ubN4d9n8Pdz3eHly9vN8NllerYrDdnZ5d1MzmWQY5tVc4rOT9/8cJUpZjBbpqk9x9/vLlf3R48fXrxQk7ebdellPX289fX97tq4u3qw@X96u3DzcX91ceb@vHb1dUNPr/7eHt3ebfa3d7uvhz8993l7eXBH6bvvv9@VRfWj9uVyMEf@o3tp9PD@uOw6v/@ebn7sDmff9zW39wQBpuPzWaol36IxU7XIoMrrn@wg5jB98s45CGYfin1djfdXIYYxxt8vRab5rvrg3ZaIw3OTLfUtcWH6Xs/@CzTD/UBn6fV66NxfDbU732cbgmDS2m6xQ7WOl2muDTdnoYw3Z0Gyfqg15/FxAQJ3bhG6Wful7meYlZEvTsEPac46Ed8HD@l@kM28yKm/mBVQu9FDxFJtzLd0XbNSWWUZGeBmwLmJ@qzAV@7lGfDVCvYOH2Ig4uq@CpenDbpMlmP6@D9tG5VSp73yPUhn1Wd1hR1izDbRIZJ@U0vJWYysxq0CWi8Ho/klgQ9ejfdUdURVV9xsGl2hlyv5zVrXvF0ftrWqsEk@aA@mEtSv4tZRZ6Pl3GkuoZRK8LocNYqt1Fp26fpGHW1IcqsSRWr2QFajJPxKRDagUVdMS1ka8pJKcEMcdqsmTrDUZN4LO0gd3CzqLl@zWJ7GQ3ajzDYggCc3KnvYU2kKM0a6mJpP4mpwCWm3Vv4uhBpD3GWbhMKf68xEVxSmzhvJsuW2V/bkTQNaHw2xVl1DStJxZw0y7bMaoRc3QKBIznTGYyD203em8hNWnBMIT6eTfNdmn2wa8Z7CpXp61mUnt/cZLcugnUa@BQBZvFcP/hkvPE6TE7fYjkipgwbuOihVT1BBam6LnyzGK@aF5Ms/EFChtksBVXJ6u5esxTlgGBUQZNSMqJgXNoIvhdk3ixw5zwnt5r3VXN1R6uKS7q5mMmI85mQwe30QGEfirPl2ooB4eCgaYvollioqgWcebZ4O1Ox6jneGHVsQfUsmqJcIJmoBpN/uESpyRjNmFM17GXKIsQ9dnQwWomJqkXmHJB0GWTjPFkl9uLpPclIucyifHFeMAEqEtQAB19xwejyXm1rA7bR9Nq2nLyvieiTQ3GDh3iAh2QS1k7wP@cR3MXD0ab0RpbOBDuaEWW2QNNpdEtddJc3sxabrq0W1smJm82leA3pHMm@Ygz05ZenI9zluyxweodDu0yQpEhE2nQFioxYvOgqBfBKk0gQddCEQhIKBYI3To8TLPLdDPu6xalGU@ay2XL2m/NsWxUa1VQAbDYCGiApipyoKcnaoiXWI1NV7WeEqFGJW71R2z6DclpZki1aRGzWDDmb3HE2UbN1WwkpLKtUDoenFJ6E03wUuJNfRllzrBjispB2T4miDh8Cqa0kwr1YG@eNyBrJIJjnfawWW4/nWq21Hv41oYluykRZ3QarebV6e95394avS1ZhvA26K2ErgcNPHupUrA5PwhIxWVQb0Vs7cAjPQElSp1KblVlRIzTwQMgpECIHEAb8APjiMr@oFRZ5O2juHY2Sl6btDZVHjdHmp8qbGWxFSK/9hNb@wjmgqiBBTgC@ZkgHUT2i3NulSru0Foop8FQjXOMB0xxZyxPiLB6SWxXRZa69Dqu4sAyK7qBGdVSfCB5lNgX0YtlBeRKpViAnWooAT0i4JDS7LhNasgquoupLDHqBWkNFY9dxXmRPz0GltwK4SE0PBZhFRTcKufIs@lh8Kbc5@HKRpbePGMLrddDjiONq7jwwbMrk0QoXmj2o4sze2XOQ96gwcGBbnD6rkjXhSwAc9j4jn2hX14q9ogchERSYoX1ppy1ZnbxYSpoSYlDroGPQakROpiiluVIkvFDbueddj2rKKgYvAFieOk9BD2YKeRvlkeyopfACAI5@PhYD2JGKIOS1b63H1pjLM68ggKZUyiZ@ItOHCLUvmkjKkxKJGEp2T2ujcpI1undCi0Ltj91vmTUhd6Q@Zbp@dEfURFnCszG2HQoNYKBG8xy2sEyPU0RgRHH2GTFgUT7jXjOf59qIBiWCIRAN7BHv2rSHBaRjPMrdNlpkNOBTqmrRagchDv0rKmsoSOjWBES/QR6KscA7HbXEQOFQXELrVQiluWXhG3k9EzVIFY73ROUy2d5g@6CSOz26FWH0TLUoFN0LBhVlFjtRhpjitg5cjUBEF1WbKdHprCHDZQF0yjnQXUQOCGxeCFyZfZBSjzdXd/OsvDYuAUyBp/4o5CV31azlUReDwDstgK3kDGiULaHFQHGP3quoSl2EzsUSWeuwEXmAi9R3yx771jp5yjp22TQwhgjkCb16iqYY5kMK4RPsnVFeE7lYCGip6FwGgSwJ0INEcnqDD8uWb2QcQtpnBp9jCktuGI3fY30ALGuKdAt@QCiz1JRAmFcS1XABjWY9aLIQqA8LmsWjtsdTw5XQA1ptOxqmSRyHoHVn8mB0YKqz1NIFA91RAIv2mJHvdrIsB72NCygvGVUkICNlcMHiiDeVmc3vIHBmHEfuEmUlZRSNmTsaEY5iokxuUmYv6J2GKfpwJvJfYa56pqCtDAv3d3qoRDBqn4FoWCQvhx2FSMLRXAbgMRSMT8QaNCTqHBlI2jOyiMDvEZUZoxYC1xi1WLQuBHBypra5rhbR//kFdx41XXQVZJC5RatcAQh2FkeNIuA1gLSAG72lIE05EE2gPkrEIONMquoSqGWvMcPtjxDhHDKhrkJpKHkcn9KNgrf6tAP0nAzbNOCZZApp6V@tAMy4smUDj0UctYhOMJpwfkGDSsdQSCJmv0D1M2RBBzPTCON0ywj04QCsom7lqGIjeArxtNQ0iSgSAt3ez@wTdCdWuH4AGzhq3Dzoz9qQEkmaC7AHewKaJG/oUVMW/X0AfBnnVS7oHckR55UVHSinOzXze4iwqSkkzWmFcpLLVPPEoZfNiz5SOjcAabNOBtJcu8okF9FepKVAHCUNYWk063ngtDeXlGdDhGazmBeQGFV@JK8KunfSCVUCpdn9QFSTCEZo@83FOFy10EpKC6jbZ7Hz2QVdzEjcG406t6T5nrUf1VMAl3W7ukZGf6d8yWj5rNYBlZz3W70xFoyA5BZQDgkVTufMLfgCKI9o0IY75BnUjEQUh9c7Ag3ua5xnIktotps4CaOpCsueuikzUsLhUbFHtFWXxoDccxWhjicwMlzSrCP3qc1zHDAyn7PAyMjwMAOciMSIjipF6lH2sKsHDGyXSuYWZWTGEQNaK5p/SuHZK@YULoBZisu@ekRGKaInNBg0W0MTP001xK5gvlkiKgwg1cwmdM4Dr4noUsz1ev2dyBFXKLFgEO8Ck0OUegLo5YDYd5HoZUI28ysqbcmE0W8pNP/ylBElRwauVg@N8UIfDGS8VmJtXowdOEU3QZPaB41aP4DAKD4ulNMHHQTUg85TMV3sfMuchHpjRXmZThj84h0Xry35KGt4RskDutFAU9DsBQtLhsyjFge@NVGbYAh/iRXCVPNAMCFcI02zC9c6BVWcCDNNGzviMSBe5lLX0SvQSoikYRzWx8BTbZpkJ79o8XpFKBg8ozaA1ZoV05QeKIdZt2jIR0@LWE5i8Ev6tqk6m7AYbPjnwwOrb1PUuM1CdDeYaX4BQCixoF@1KHXFLOfyPRCCYwMC1BfU15D23qqK1E1oOegkKJK9o7Ex0N1MDY3jDZpWYT6LVr3zhrIvt@fykpzB@C/RyN2BNLYGA725DeyGz8yi6@3elT3b442H5r3JeIJhiTK5wWSgEEVgoGbLPEkFLzhV0aCrAFQzXx6IqjLkCplRHA3tTFnSvPEZj9GSc6B3/yL3Z4GmNV5D0VHTBn5oRt4R1MhYWiO9syaS@W02vPmxh4bBwPQQQYZ2gV4GAcnJKdUtR5K9MyjUMpn99xubIqhnY6bcZCZZUFhzXiDXwHCsa59ZkUSqLYnotrmPJOH7WCcXHI@6xsKz8Xmw1AeTCf1OsGgCIqVUURam6LO9E/OYfAR6OyYDxhoLM0W4j9f5M/BNJ4y9LBN80PGFICkkhMr51/9dvP2w@@Xu68sff/r61y83u@uri/HD3z/s7t9@vL3@@vLn/wM)

Explained:

```
q = ""                  // define `q` as the empty string
j = join                // define `j` as the join function
$ h a                   // function $ of horses `h` and array `a`
 = replaceSubString     // replace all
  " 0"                  // zeroes with spaces before them
  "  "                  // with two spaces
  (                     // (in the string)
   " QUINELLA" +        // " QUINELLA" prepended to
   (                    // (the string created by)
    j                   // joining arg2 with arg1
     (                  // (the separator string)
      "\n" +            // newline prepended to
      j "+"             // joining arg2 with plusses
       (repeatn 16      // a list with 16 of
        "-----")        // string with 5 dashes
      + "\n"            // prepended to a newline
     )
     [                  // (a list made out of)
      j "|"             // joining arg2 with vertical pipes
       [                // (a list made out of)
        q <+            // stringifying
        cjustify 5 [    // center-aligning a list of
         c              // character `c`
         \\ c <-:       // for every `c` in the string
          ? h a u v     // (the thing that goes in the cell)
        ]
        \\ v <- [0..15] // for every `v` from 0 to 15
       ]
       \\ u <- [0..8]   // for every `u` from 0 to 8
     ]
   ) % (9, 9^9)         // drop 9 elements off the front
  )
? h a u v               // function ? of `h` `a` `u` and `v`
 | u < 1                // if `u` is zero
  = q <+ v rem 15       // stringify `v` modulo 15
 | v > 14               // if `v` is 15
  = q <+ u rem 8        // stringify `u` modulo 8
 | u > 7                // if `u` is 8
  | v > 7               // if `v` is more than 7
   = q <+ v             // stringify `v`
  = q <+                // otherwise stringify
  (v+7) *               // `v` plus 7 unless
  sign(v rem 7)         // `v` is 7 or zero
 | u == v               // if `u` equals `v`
  = u + 7 <+            // stringify `u` plus 7 and append
  "\\" <+ v             // a slash and the stringification of v
 | v < 1                // if `v` is zero
  | u > 1               // if `u` is more than 1
   = q <+ u + 7         // stringify `u` + 7
  = q                   // empty string
 # p =                  // define `p` as
  sort                  // the sorted
   [                    // (list of horse numbers)
    k +                 // k plus
    if(u >= v)
     7                  // if u >= v, 7
     0                  // else zero
    \\ k <- [u, v]      // for every `k` in u and v
   ]
 # r =                  // define `r` as
  sum                   // the sum of
   [                    // (the bets on those horses)
    z                   // the bet `z`
    \\ (x, y, z) <- a   // for every subarray
    | [x, y] == p       // where the horse pair matches `p`
   ]
 | r > 0.0              // if `r` is greater than zero
  # r =                 // redefine `r` as
   sum                  // the sum of
    (map thd3 a)        // every bet
   / r                  // divided by the previous `r`
   / 2E0                // divided by two
  | r < 9.95            // if r is less than 9.95
   = snd                // the second element of
    (                   // (the tuple with the closest matching odd)
     sort               // sort the
      [                 // (list of potential odds)
       (                // (tuple with)
        abs(e - r)      // the difference between `r` and the odd `e`
        , e <+ ".0"     // and the stringification of `e`
       )                // for every `e` in the list of odds
       \\ e <- [1.1, 1.2..1E1] 
      ] !! 0            // the first element
    ) % (0, 2)          // "round" the number
  = q <+ toInt r        // otherwise stringify and round `r`
 | p!!1 < h             // if the bet was actually zero
  = "999"               // the odds are 999
 = q                    // otherwise there isn't a horse
```